# Binding to Button Visibility

Tags: wpf, mvvm, tabitem

I have the following Style for a `TabItem`

```
<Style x:Key="SubStudioTabItem" TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}">
  <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{x:Null}"/>
  <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
  <Setter Property="Template">
     <Setter.Value>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}">
           <Grid Height="20" 
                        Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" 
                        SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
              <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                 <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                 <ColumnDefinition Width="20"/>
              </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
              <ContentPresenter Grid.Column="0" 
                                Margin="10,0,10,0" 
                                HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
                                VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                                ContentSource="Header" />
              <Button Grid.Column="1" 
                      x:Name="CloseButton" 
                      Width="15" 
                      Height="15" 
                      HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
                      VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                      DockPanel.Dock="Right" 
                      AttachedCommand:CommandBehavior.Event="Click"
                      AttachedCommand:CommandBehavior.Command="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Window}}, 
                                                                        Path=DataContext.CloseWorkspaceCommand}">
              ...
```

Now I want to make the visibility of the `Button` on the `TabItem` optional which can be used in a `DataTemplate` like

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="WorkspaceTemplate">
    <TabControl x:Name="tabControl" 
                IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="true" 
                Style="{StaticResource StudioTabControl}"
                ItemsSource="{Binding Workspaces}" 
                SelectedIndex="{Binding SelectedIndex, NotifyOnSourceUpdated=True, Mode=TwoWay}">
        <TabControl.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="TabItem" 
                   BasedOn="{StaticResource SubStudioTabItem}">
                <Setter Property="??Button.Visibility??" Value="{Binding Path=Display, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibiltyConverter}}"/>
            </Style>
        </TabControl.ItemContainerStyle>
    </TabControl>
</DataTemplate>
```

**How can I set the state of the visibility of the button on the `TabItem` from the `DataTemplate`?**

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In that case, I would create an *attached* property, such as type of `Visibility` and would make a `TemplateBinding` in the `Style`, something like this:

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}">
...
    <Button Grid.Column="1" 
                x:Name="CloseButton" 
                Visibility="{TemplateBinding local:MyClass.ButtonVisibility}"
                ...
    </Button>
```

And for `TabItem` in `<ItemContainerStyle>` would write this (or somewhere else):

```
<Style TargetType="TabItem" BasedOn="{StaticResource SubStudioTabItem}">
    <Setter Property="local:MyClass.ButtonVisibility" Value="{Binding Path=Display, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibiltyConverter}}"/>
</Style>
```

**`Edit:`**

I created a project that implements this method. In the project tried to follow the *MVVM* pattern. The structure of the project:

[image]

Start in order, in folder `AttachedProperties` there is an attached property, which is responsible for the appearance of the `Button`.

The code of `ButtonVisibility.cs`:

```
using System;
using System.Windows;

public class ButtonVisibilityPro : DependencyObject
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ButtonVisibilityProperty;

    public static void SetButtonVisibility(DependencyObject DepObject, Visibility value)
    {
        DepObject.SetValue(ButtonVisibilityProperty, value);
    }

    public static Visibility GetButtonVisibility(DependencyObject DepObject)
    {
        return (Visibility)DepObject.GetValue(ButtonVisibilityProperty);
    }

    static ButtonVisibilityPro()
    {
        PropertyMetadata MyPropertyMetadata = new PropertyMetadata(Visibility.Collapsed);

        ButtonVisibilityProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("ButtonVisibility",
                                                            typeof(Visibility),
                                                            typeof(ButtonVisibilityPro),
                                                            MyPropertyMetadata);
    }
}
```

The data model is `ButtonModel`, wherein the boolean property is `ButtonDisplay`. This class inherits from the `ViewModelBase`, that implements *INotifyPropertyChanged*.

**`ButtonModel.cs`**

```
using System;
using ButtonVisibilityHelp.ViewModels;

namespace ButtonVisibilityHelp.Models
{
    public class ButtonModel : ViewModelBase
    {
        private bool _buttonDisplay = false;

        public bool ButtonDisplay
        {
            get 
            {
                return _buttonDisplay; 
            }

            set
            {
                _buttonDisplay = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("ButtonDisplay");             
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**`ViewModelBase.cs`**

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;

namespace ButtonVisibilityHelp.ViewModels
{
    public class ViewModelBase : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        protected void NotifyPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**`ButtonViewModel.cs`**

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows;

using ButtonVisibilityHelp.Models;
using ButtonVisibilityHelp.Workers;

namespace ButtonVisibilityHelp.ViewModels
{
    public class ButtonViewModel : ViewModelBase
    {
        private ButtonModel _buttonModel;

        private ICommand _hideButtonCommand = null;
        private ICommand _showButtonCommand = null;

        public ButtonModel ButtonModel
        {
            get
            {
                return _buttonModel;
            }

            set
            {
                _buttonModel = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("ButtonModel");
            }
        }

        public ICommand HideButtonCommand
        {
            get
            {
                if (_hideButtonCommand == null)
                {
                    _hideButtonCommand = new RelayCommand(param => this.HideButton(), null);
                }

                return _hideButtonCommand;
            }
        }

        public ICommand ShowButtonCommand
        {
            get
            {
                if (_showButtonCommand == null)
                {
                    _showButtonCommand = new RelayCommand(param => this.ShowButton(), null);
                }

                return _showButtonCommand;
            }
        }

        public ButtonViewModel()
        {
            ButtonModel = new ButtonModel();
        }

        private void HideButton() 
        {            
            ButtonModel.ButtonDisplay = false;
        }

        private void ShowButton() 
        {
            ButtonModel.ButtonDisplay = true;
        }
    }
}
```

**`RelayCommand.cs`**

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Input;

namespace ButtonVisibilityHelp.Workers
{
    public class RelayCommand : ICommand
    {
        private readonly Action<object> _execute;
        private readonly Predicate<object> _canExecute;

        public RelayCommand(Action<object> execute) : this(execute, null)
        {
        }

        public RelayCommand(Action<object> execute, Predicate<object> canExecute)
        {
            if (execute == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("execute");
            }

            _execute = execute;
            _canExecute = canExecute;
        }

        public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
        {
            return _canExecute == null ? true : _canExecute(parameter);
        }

        public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
        {
            add
            {
                CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value;
            }

            remove
            {
                CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value;
            }
        }

        public void Execute(object parameter)
        {
            _execute(parameter);
        }
    }
}
```

Below is a piece of XAML code that is in the style of `TabItem`:

```
<Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}">
                <Grid Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="20"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                    <Border Grid.Column="0" SnapsToDevicePixels="True" Name="Border" Margin="0,0,2,0" Padding="2" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" CornerRadius="0">
                        <ContentPresenter Name="ContentSite" 
                                              HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                                              Margin="5,5,5,5"
                                              VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                                              RecognizesAccessKey="True" 
                                              ContentSource="Header" />                            
                    </Border>

                    <!-- Here TemplateBinding for Visibility -->
                    <Button Name="CloseButton" Style="{StaticResource CloseButton}" 
                                Visibility="{TemplateBinding AttachedProperties:ButtonVisibilityPro.ButtonVisibility}" 
                                Grid.Column="1" Width="14" Height="14" HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
                </Grid>

                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="TabStripPlacement" Value="Bottom">
                        <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="CornerRadius" Value="0,0,0,0" />
                    </Trigger>                            
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
</Setter>
```

XAML of `MainWindow`:

```
<Window x:Class="ButtonVisibilityHelp.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:ViewModels="clr-namespace:ButtonVisibilityHelp.ViewModels"
    xmlns:AttachedProperties="clr-namespace:ButtonVisibilityHelp.AttachedProperties"
    WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">

    <Window.Resources>
        <ViewModels:ButtonViewModel x:Key="MyButtonViewModel" />
        <BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="BooleanToVisibilityConverter" />
    </Window.Resources>

    <Grid DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource MyButtonViewModel}}">
        <TabControl>
            <TabControl.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type TabItem}}">
                    <Setter Property="AttachedProperties:ButtonVisibilityPro.ButtonVisibility" Value="{Binding Path=ButtonModel.ButtonDisplay, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}" />
                </Style>
            </TabControl.ItemContainerStyle>

            <TabItem Header="Test1">
                <StackPanel>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding ButtonModel.ButtonDisplay, StringFormat=ButtonDisplay: {0}, Mode=TwoWay}" HorizontalAlignment="Right" />

                    <Button Name="ShowInTest1" Command="{Binding ShowButtonCommand}" Width="100" Height="30" Content="Show me" HorizontalAlignment="Right" />
                    <Button Name="HideInTest1" Command="{Binding HideButtonCommand}" Width="100" Height="30" Content="Hide me" HorizontalAlignment="Right" />                   
                </StackPanel>
            </TabItem>

            <TabItem Header="Test2">
                <StackPanel>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding ButtonModel.ButtonDisplay, StringFormat=ButtonDisplay: {0}, Mode=TwoWay}" HorizontalAlignment="Right" />

                    <Button Name="ShowInTest2" Command="{Binding ShowButtonCommand}" Width="100" Height="30" Content="Show me" HorizontalAlignment="Right" />
                    <Button Name="HideInTest2" Command="{Binding HideButtonCommand}" Width="100" Height="30" Content="Hide me" HorizontalAlignment="Right" />
                </StackPanel>
            </TabItem>
        </TabControl>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

`Output`

Show me:

[image]

Hide me:

[image]

The complete code example is available at this [link](https://skydrive.live.com/redir?resid=3FC95A33B3F2DE8A!111&authkey=!ADtgl_a2tqh4E5Y).

Comment: I am having difficulty with this example. Can you make it more complete?

Comment: @Killercam: Yes, as will the time, I'll do. I'm sorry, that immediately did not provide the full code.

Comment: this is absolute quality! You have gone out of your way here and it is most appreciated. I am away this week, but when I am back I will bounty this. Have a great week and thanks again...

Answer (score 0):

Set the `Tag` property on your `TabItem` in style like below :

```
<TabControl.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="TabItem" 
               BasedOn="{StaticResource SubStudioTabItem}">
            <Setter Property="Tag" Value="{Binding IsVisible, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}"/>
        </Style>
    </TabControl.ItemContainerStyle>
```

And then in `ControlTemplate` add `DataTrigger` to set the `Visibility` of CloseButton depending on Tag property

```
<ControlTemplate.Triggers>
   <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Tag}", Value="false">
     <Setter Property="Visibility" TargetName="CloseButton" Value="Collapsed"/>
     </DataTrigger>
</ControlTemplate.Triggers>
```

Comment: But this is not allowing me to bind to the button's visibility. I need to change the visibility of the button depending on the ViewModel loaded.

Comment: see the updated answer..you can bind the Tag property to VM property IsVisible and then use it in ControlTemplate trigger